# strtod truncates decimals when used in Qt project

Tags: c, qt

I am currently debugging code that sometimes works and sometimes does not.
It is an OBJ file loader and I found the part that makes problems:

```
double val = strtod(str, &endptr);
```

To explain the problem I will give you an example of the values after `strtod` was called.

```
str = "-0.021344"
val = -0
*endptr = '.'
```

Behind that line error checking is done and if `*endptr != '\0'` an error is thrown.
Now of course an error is thrown because `strtod` marked the dot as the end of the number,
but why is this so? Also note that I only encounter this error when using the code in QT projects.

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: Don't know, but maybe Qt does something with the locale and now the `strtod` function expects a german number. What happens with `"-0,021344"`?

Comment: Maybe you're using a *[locale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_07)* for which the decimal point is not `.`. Try `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");` before the `strtod` statement.

Comment: @pmg This is also the default for plain C and C++ programs.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: correct, but maybe the OP changed it directly or through the use of some library function ...

Comment: @pmg yeah Qt will almost certainly load the system locale. My comment was was just a side note.

Comment: @pmg Write your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you're using a *[locale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_07)* for which the decimal point is not `.`. Try `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");` before the `strtod` statement.

Note: I don't know how locale and QT behave together. You may want to save and restore the locale ...

```
char *saved_locale;
saved_locale = setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");
/* do your strtod thing */
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, saved_locale);
```

Comment: The Qt way of doing this is: `QLocale::setDefault(QLocale::C);`. Of course that is equivalent to `LC_ALL`.

Comment: Thank you, both for your answers they saved me a lot of headache.

Comment: I have no idea what the C++ or QT way is :-)

Comment: Many locale categories (absolutely `LC_CTYPE`) need to be set to the user's preferred locale for proper program behavior. But `LC_NUMERIC` is purely harmful and should always be set to `"C"`. Math/numbers are not a cultural convention. They're math. And everybody knows math is absolute. :-) Anyway, the point is don't just set it all to C; rather, fix `LC_NUMERIC` to be C.

Comment: I strongly urge the save / restore approach -- my case was that the user was in the EU with LCID=1036, and "," as the decimal point character, but their database was in the US with LCID=1033 and "." as the decimal point.  The numeric string value was coming from the database, but to keep everything else looking EU local, we switched the locale just for the DB read.

Comment: The [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/setlocale) say that `setlocale` returns the locale *after applying the changes*, so this permanently sets the locale to `"C"`. You should call `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, NULL);` to retrieve the original locale.

Answer (score 4):

All C functions that work with textual representations are affected by locale.

What is your locale? In some, the decimal point is actually `,`.

Comment: I don't know what my locale is, because I never cared about it up to now. Apparently QT changes it, because `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");` fixed it.

Comment: @Nobody Qt will load the system locale, to make sure that the Qt widgets behave the same way as the rest of the system. Actually using `setlocale` isn't such a good idea. If you really want to use "C" locale, you should go all the way: `setlocale(LC_ALL,"C");` or the Qt way: `QLocale::setDefault(QLocale::C);`

Answer (score 1):

The decimal point is locale-dependent.

> **From [the manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod):**
>
> A *decimal number* consists of a nonempty sequence of decimal digits possibly containing a radix character (decimal point, locale dependent, usually ''.''), optionally followed by a decimal exponent. A decimal exponent consists of an ''E'' or ''e'', followed by an optional plus or minus sign, followed by a non-empty sequence of decimal digits, and indicates multiplication by a power of 10.